# How can I always show my user's 'library' folder in macOS Sierra?

Tags: mac, finder, macos, library

I’ve just upgraded to a much newer Mac after having been on an old MBP running Snow Leopard. There’s a lot to learn in the major jump from 10.6 to 10.12. One change is that my user’s Library folder is invisible.

I did Google this and see I can hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key to make the Library folder visible when I need it to be, but is there a way to always make it visible so I don’t have to do this extra step every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Probably the easiest way is:

1. Click on the Finder icon in your Dock (usually the very first icon)
2. In the Finder window that appears, click on your username in the Sidebar (see note at end if it's not listed)
3. Now go to View > Show View Options (or press <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>)
4. Now tick the Checkbox next to the Show Library Folder option (it's the bottom checkbox - see screenshot below)

[image]

5. Now your Library folder will remain visible as you were previously used to.

**NOTE:** If your username is not visible in the Sidebar, then go to Finder > Preferences, select the Sidebar tab and then select the checkbox next to your username at the bottom of the Favourites list.

Comment: Are you certain that the username appears by default in the sidebar. I thought for the username to appear, you first had to select the username in Finder sidebar preferences.

Comment: Hmm, I think it's always been there for me by default, but just to be safe I've added a note at the end of my answer. Thanks for the feedback! :)

Comment: @Monomeeth The linked duplicate has a method of always getting to the Home folder, regardless of whether it's in the sidebar, using the keyboard shortcut. Alternatively, you can use the Go menu in Finder.